# Power BI - Creating a new Table using current fields (maybe some transformation)

Tags: powerbi, dataset, dax

I have a table in my Power BI data set as below.

```
ID       Type         ActualDate
1        HoT          2022-01-11
1        Exchanges    2022-03-11
1        Completion   2022-05-16
2        Hot          2022-03-15
2        Exchanges    2022-04-04
2        Completion   2022-05-10
```

Objective: Create a new table formatting this as per the below

```
ID       Hot ActualDate    Exchange ActualDate    Completion ActualDate
1        2022-01-11        2022-03-11             2022-05-16
2        2022-03-15        2022-04-04             2022-05-10
```

In SQL I would do something like:

```
SELECT 
       ID,
    CASE WHEN Type = HoT THEN ActualDate END as [HoT ActualDate],
    CASE WHEN Type = Exchanges THEN [ActualDate] as [Exchange ActualDate],
    CASE WHEN Type = Completion THEN [ActualDate] as [Completions ActualDate]
FROM
      Table A
```

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query (`Home=>Transform` in PBI), it is a Pivot with no aggregation operation:

```
let

//Change Source line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table9"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Type", type text}, {"ActualDate", type date}}),

//Capitalize each word in the Type column since PQ is case-sensitive
    #"Capitalized Each Word" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Type", Text.Proper, type text}}),

//Concatenate Type with "Actual Date" to create the new column headers
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Capitalized Each Word", "Column Headers", each [Type] & " ActualDate", type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Type"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[#"Column Headers"]), "Column Headers", "ActualDate")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]